# US Senate/Congress Contact Info API

Tags: usa, government, api

Is there an API to get the email addresses or other contact info of US senators and representatives by postal code? Or, is there some way of getting the email addresses of all US senators and representatives linked to postal codes (perhaps in JSON of CSV format)?

Also, which states' representatives have publicly disclosed email addresses? Are there any APIs for those as well?

Answer (score 2):

email congress is a service that looks up constituents by address, then returns their representatives to be emailed.
https://emailcongress.us/
source:
https://github.com/sunlightlabs/the-phantom-mask
[disclaimer]:
i work for sunlight labs